# How to print fedex lable in Magento

Tags: magento, fedex

I need to know how I can be able to print FedEx label through Magento.

Do I need to buy extension? if yes, which one you recommend ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Shippo Magento (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shippo.html) extension to easily print FedEx labels for your Magento orders. Shippo also supports other carriers in case you want to switch / expand in the future! The app installation is very easy and you can get started in minutes.